# Error creating foreign key on "Column Name" (check data types)?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys, sqldatatypes

I'm new in dealing with databases and specially with MySQL, I'm using "phpmyadmin" as client, Here I'm trying to set "`section_year`"column from "`Attendance`" table  as a `FOREIGN KEY` to another column having the same name "section_year" from "section" table , it returns ERROR MSG always said checking the data types although I checked it very well and more than once!

The same problem occurs when I tried to make the same thing with "`Section_semester`"

The following URLs are linking you to images that shows the tables and their columns and shows that the columns - marked with red- have the same datatype in two tables!

[attendance table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hw1nb.png)

[section table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B76XJ.png)

But, I'm created a `FOREIGN KEY` from attendance table to the same table that I intend to add more `FOREIGN KEY` to it, without any ERROR MSG.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Please in code questions give a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove Primary and Unique from every foreign key.
2. Your both tables have a lot of Primary keys and Unique.

[image: Pictures of key means Primary key. All] Pictures of key means Primary key. Others with same names but wihout keys are foreign keys. You must have 3 tables when is not relationship between them One -> Many, like here. Also, you must have tables: teachers and courses:

```
Table: teachers
teacher_id primary key
name
etc

Table: courses
course_id primary key
name
description
etc
```

Comment: how ? if i remove both of them from being primary keys , I can't make a foreign key between them !

Comment: In both tables, you have fields section_year and section_semester and in both tables, its fields have Primary key and Unique. It can not be. Only in one table, table one, fields can be primary and unique. In all other tables, its can not be Primary and Uniques.

Comment: Also, your both tables have a lot of Primary keys and Unique. In a comment, I will help you organize.

Comment: Let's talk about tables' relationship.  Which table is ONE, wich table is MANY?

Comment: @GhaidaMurrar I'm going to write SQL for your database and give you here link. Moment. All is wrong in your database.

Comment: Thank u , waiting for ur suggestions , But notice that i need all of these Primary keys as it in my tables .

Answer (score 0):

OMG !!!
I've just tried something Without any hope that it will work , BUT It works with me and solved the probleeem !!

In each of columns that i used in the relation -FOREIGN KEY- i pressed on " index " option in the structure of it's table , and then "ok" , after that i tried to add a foreign key between them and things are done without ANY ERROR MSG .